# Testing Rails Metal With Cucumber/rSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber

I'm trying to stub a third party service that my metal talks to. It seems rspec mocks/stubs don't extend all the way to the Metal.

When I call stubbed methods on objects, it calls the original one and not the stubbed one.

Any idea of how I can have rSpec doubles extend all the way to the metal?

Thanks.

-Nash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using [Fakeweb](http://fakeweb.rubyforge.org/) instead? This allows you to block all outgoing traffic and send a custom response instead. This way you don't even have to write a mock. It's very lightweight and easy to use.

Comment: I've used Fakeweb before. It's really cool, but maybe overkill to use just for this instance.

It turns out my problem was in the step definition I was using HTTParty to post to the metal, which was using the environment defined in passenger (development) and not the test environment.

The fix was to use webrat visit(url, :post, data) to have execute in test mode.

Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using WebMock http://github.com/bblimke/webmock